# Loading startup script files after vmlinuz is being loaded on Trusty Tahr

Tags: startup

May I know step by step in loading startup script files after vmlinuz kernel is being loaded on Trusty Tahr?

Comment: What is it that you're looking for, exactly?

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I think I've got my answer from muru that after kernel is loaded then it will be processed by Upstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the kernel is loaded, it runs `/sbin/init`, which in Ubuntu is Upstart as of now. Then Upstart does its thing. The details of Upstart's working is a bit involved, and you should read the [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) for more information, in particular [the Startup section](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#startup). Also have a look the section on [boot process and init](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_04_02.html) in the TLDP's *Introduction to Linux*.